# How to change the format in which google analytics reports exceptions in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, crash-reports

I'm integrating google analytics to my iOS application and I want google analytics to track all the uncaught exceptions. For this, I use the line:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
```

When using automatic exception measurement, the official documentations says:

> By default, the description field is automatically set using the exception type, class name, method name and thread name.

My question is: There is some way for changing this behavior. I mean, how can I set a custom value to the description field?

Answer (score 0):

GAI is intercepting an un-handled exception and processing the exception to raise a fatal exception GA hit.  If you wanted to override this, you wouldn't be able to use the automatic tracking, instead you'd have to capture and parse the exception yourself, and manually raise the event.

Here's a blog post showing you how you might handle an exception:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html